# Checking audio file is playing or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, audio

After pressing play button audio is playing in html , By calling certain function i want to identify weather the file is playing or player is in idle state?How can i achieve this?Here is my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`paused` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Properties), which is a boolean indicating whether the media is currently paused or playing.

```
if($("audio").prop("paused")) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can do it easily without jQuery:

```
if(document.getElementById("myAudioId").paused) {
    ...
}
```

(assuming you give the `<audio>` tag an `id` property)